# A Dold-Thom style construction of a cohomology class from a sphere bundle

Tags: homotopy-theory, fibre-bundles

Re-reading my comment to the question https://mathoverflow.net/q/195912/41291 I suddenly realized that I do not understand something crucial about it. For the purposes of that crucial thing let me reformulate it slightly.

I would like to construct from a bundle $E\to B$ with fibre $S^n$ over a (sufficiently nice) space $B$ a class in $H^{n+1}(B;\mathbb Z)$. To name such a class, it suffices to exhibit a bundle with fibre $K(\mathbb Z,n)$ over $B$.

In that comment I just said to perform the "fibrewise infinite symmetric power construction", and now I realize I do not know what precisely this means.

Given any map $f:X\to Y$ whatsoever **with a compatible choice of basepoints in fibers** - that is, with a section $s:Y\to X$ of $f$ - it is indeed seemingly straightforward to construct the fibrewise infinite symmetric power: it is
$$
\left.\left(\coprod_n\ \underbrace{X\times_YX\times_Y\cdots\times_YX}_{n\textrm{ times}}\right)\right/_{\displaystyle\sim}
$$
where $\sim$ is the smallest equivalence relation identifying $(x_1,...,x_n)$ with $(x_{\sigma(1)},...,x_{\sigma(n)})$ for any permutation $\sigma$ and moreover identifying $(x_1,...,x_n)$ (in the $n$th component) with $(x_1,...,x_n,sf(x_n))$ (in the $n+1$st component).

However it turns out there are some problems. First, what to do with $n=0$? In the "ordinary" (non-fibrewise) infinite symmetric power the $0$-tuple $()$ simply gets identified with all $n$-tuples consisting entirely of the basepoints but I cannot figure out what to do in the fibrewise version. Just start with $n=1$? (Concerning this one - as pointed out in the comment below, the 0th piece is just $Y$ as it is the limit of an empty diagram in (spaces over $Y$), i. e. the terminal object of the latter category).

Second, more serious problem is that if I have a nontrivial bundle (which is the only interesting case) I do not have any compatible choice of basepoints in the fibres. I could freely add basepoints to the fibres, i. e. switch to $f_+:=(f,\textrm{identity}):X\coprod Y\to Y$, but would it give correct result in the sphere bundle case? That is, which of the following is the correct way to produce a $K(\mathbb Z,n)$ from $S^n$: (a) choose a basepoint in $S^n$ and take infinite symmetric power with respect to it or (b) take infinite symmetric power of $S^n_+$, i. e. of the sphere with a disjoint basepoint added?

Also, there is a possibility to form a basepoint-free version of this. The infinite symmetric power of a space $F$ is the free commutative topological monoid on $F$, which becomes group-like if $F$ is connected. But actually one can also form the free topological "zeroless abelian group"; this is the structure with a ternary operation, denoted $(x,y,z)\mapsto x+_yz$ which satisfies
\begin{align*}
&x+_yy=x,\\
&x+_yz=z+_yx
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
&(x+_yz)+_tu=x+_y(z+_tu)
\end{align*}
for all $x,y,z,t,u$. Fixing any $y$ gives an abelian group structure with addition $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1+_yx_2$, zero $y$ and inverse $-_yx:=y+_xy$, and choosing different $y$ produces (canonically) isomorphic groups. Conversely, any abelian group has such structure given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto x-y+z$. All this is well known for many years, I think it must be called folklore.

Now it is straightforward to form a free such structure on a space $F$ - 
just take $\left(\coprod_{n\ge0}F^{2n+1}\right)/\sim$ where $\sim$ identifies $(x_0,y_1,x_1,y_2,...,y_n,x_n)$ with $(x_{\sigma(0)},y_{\tau(1)},x_{\sigma(1)},y_{\tau(2)},...,y_{\tau(n)},x_{\sigma(n)})$ for any permutations $\sigma$ of $\{0,1,...,n\}$ and $\tau$ of $\{1,...,n\}$ and moreover identifies $(x_0,y_1,x_1,y_2,...,y_n,x_n)$ with $(x_0,y_1,x_1,y_2,...,y_n,x_n,y,y)$.

Obviously this can be performed fibrewise, and one does not need any basepoints; but once again, does this give correct result? In particular, does the above (non-fibrewise basepoint-free) version produce a $K(\mathbb Z,n)$ from $S^n$?

Comment: For your first and easiest question regarding the case $n=0$: the 0th fibered power of $X$ over $Y$ is just equal to $Y$.

Comment: @DanPetersen Yes of course, thank you, I'll add this (with hopefully correct justification, although this might be also used by convention).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your second question is that you need to pick a basepoint in $S^n$. Recall that Dold-Thom tells you that $\pi_i$ of the infinite symmetric product recovers the reduced homology of a connected pointed space. If you adjoin a basepoint, the resulting space has nonzero reduced $H_0$, so the resulting infinite symmetric product has nonzero $\pi_0$, and you won't get the $B^n \mathbb{Z}$ you want.

Note also that even if you knew that this sphere bundle came from a vector bundle, you would still need a piece of additional data to get an Euler class from it: namely, an orientation. So some kind of extra data is unavoidable.

Comment: Sorry I am confused by that - the basepoint becomes zero of the resulting topological group anyway, no? So the resulting group must still be connected I think.

Comment: And concerning the second part - maybe what I obtain should not be called Euler class, but in any case I do obtain something in $H^{n+1}(\_,\mathbb Z)$, don't I?

Comment: The group is connected if the original space is connected, but $S^n$ with a basepoint adjoined is not. Concerning the second part, this doesn't seem true for $n = 1$.

Comment: Now that you say it - yes I agree it looks suspicious, even for $n=0$. But I don't understand where is the problem with that fibrewise construction. Maybe I must just honestly find out what happens with, say, double covering of the circle...

Comment: You don't (a priori) get something in $H^{n+1}$ because this construction gives a $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$-bundle, not a _principal_ $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$-bundle.

Comment: @EricWofsey AHA this seems to be the key! Hopefully I can figure out exactly what missing data makes the difference... And also, non-principal $K(\mathbb Z,n)$ bundles are still classified by something too, right? Does it immediately drop down to just $\mathbb Z/2$ coefficients??

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Non-principal bundles will be classified by the classifying space of the group of self-homeomorphisms of $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ in general.  This might seem fairly unnatural (it depends on the specific $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ space used); you could reduce the structure group to the group of self-homotopy equivalences to get something more canonical.  But that group is just a discrete $\mathbb{Z}/2$, and the associated class in $H^1(-,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is just the orientation class of your sphere bundle.

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry, I'm confused again - do you mean homotopy classes of self-homotopy equivalences? Then this would mean going in the "opposite direction" - not **reducing** the structure group but rather passing to the discrete **quotient** (of a larger group, but I think it can be also realized as quotient of homeomorphisms). Whereas reducing would mean passing to a subgroup or to a connective cover, no? For example, capturing principal bundles would mean reducing the structure group to the self-homeomorphisms given by the action of (a topological group model of) $K(\mathbb Z,n)$ on itself.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Sorry, you're right, "reduce" was the wrong word.  I meant looking at the (not a priori discrete) space of pointed self-homotopy equivalences, which is a union of connected components in the space of all pointed self-maps.  In the case of an Eilenberg-MacLane space, these components happen to be contractible, so you get the same thing (up to homotopy) as you would if you just took homotopy classes of equivalences.